# Memory leaks ram java program with opencv and processing

Tags: java, opencv

i have this code in java and memory in ram almost explodes in just a few seconds. I release the IplImage "imagensMedia ". Why??

EDIT: This function runs many times per second

```
int largura=1280;
int altura=800;

IplImage[] imagens = new IplImage[5];
IplImage imagensSoma=cvCreateImage(cvSize(largura,altura), 32, 3);
int indiceImagem=0;

for(x=0; x<imagens.length;x++)
   imagens[x]=cvCreateImage(cvSize(largura,altura), 8, 3);

public void imageArrayBuilder() //Constroi Array de Imagens e a Sua Media
{
    int z;
    IplImage imagensMedia =cvCreateImage(cvSize(largura,altura), 8, 3);

    cam.read();
    opencv.copy(cam.get());

    if(imagemTotalFlag)
    {
        cvSub(imagensSoma,imagens[indiceImagem],imagensSoma, null);
        cvAcc(opencv.Buffer, imagensSoma, null);
        cvConvertScale(imagensSoma, imagensMedia, 1.0/imagens.length,0);
        cvCopy(opencv.Buffer,imagens[indiceImagem],null);
        indiceImagem++;
        if(indiceImagem==imagens.length)
            indiceImagem=0;
        opencv.copy(imagensMedia);    
    }
    else
    {
        if(indiceImagem<imagens.length)
        {
            cvCopy(opencv.Buffer,imagens[indiceImagem],null);
            indiceImagem++;
            if(indiceImagem==imagens.length)
            {
                imagemTotalFlag=true;
                for(z = 0; z < imagens.length; z++)
                    cvAcc(imagens[z], imagensSoma, null);
                cvConvertScale(imagensSoma, imagensMedia, 1.0/imagens.length,0);
                indiceImagem=0;
                opencv.copy(imagensMedia);
            }
        }
    }
    cvReleaseImage(imagensMedia);   
}
```

Someone help me please...

Comment: what do you mean by explodes? does it explode after you release the image, how big is it?

Comment: This function have a big memory leak. after 20 seconds the program have 1.5GB RAM... oh, i forgot, this fucntion runs many times per second.

Comment: Images are very large you appear to be copying them to an array which is not being cleared? I would expect a very large footprint. How big is the array supposed to be? 1000 images will easily take 1GB.

Comment: Sorry i forgot some line codes before the function. i edited the code. The array is fixed, only 5 images.

Comment: @Luis How big are the images then, in pixels?

Comment: 1280*800. But the array only saves 5 images... That dont take no more than 10MB maybe..

Comment: Keep in mind that images, once expanded in memory, can be enormous.  Very often a single pixel is represented by 4-8 bytes.  A file that is only a few hundred K on disk can expand to hundreds of MB.

Comment: Your code is hard to understand and does not even compile. Please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) which demonstrates your problem so we can all help you more effectively.

Comment: Jesse Webb. This is only a parte of the program. Maybe i forgot a variable or two..

I think i solved the problem by calling System.gc(). But my processor screems a little bit now :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think the concept of a "memory leak" really applies in java, as it is a garbage collected language (references are automatically deleted when no other objects refer to them). The comments have given a few possibilities about where the memory is being used; I would recommend looking into how garbage collection works (see [this link](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/04/garbage-collection-in-java.html) for starters). If all else fails, calling `System.gc()` will run the garbage collector, or more specifically:

> Calling the gc method suggests that the Java Virtual Machine expend effort toward recycling unused objects in order to make the memory they currently occupy available for quick reuse. When control returns from the method call, the Java Virtual Machine has made a best effort to reclaim space from all discarded objects.

Beyond that, check for infinite loops or infinite recursion.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. But if you use opencv and IplImage in any language you have to release memory..

Comment: I tested with System.gc(). It worked, but my processor increased from 15 to 40% now

Comment: @LuisCarlos Well I suppose that makes sense as is expending a lot of effort towards removing references... I don't know how to fix it, however. Maybe a `Threed.sleep()` call every now and then?

Comment: Calling System.gc() should make no difference (except on Android, where it has a non-Java-heap side-effect).  All it does is cause GC to run more frequently than it would otherwise, chewing up CPU.

Comment: @HotLicks "cause GC to run more frequently than it would otherwise" is exactly what needs to happen. Unused objects are taking up memory; this removes them faster.

Comment: Well, i found the problem, this lines:
`code`
    cam.read();
    opencv.copy(cam.get());

have a bug, leak memory related..
Now i do it like this:
        capture = new OpenCVFrameGrabber(1);
        capture.setImageHeight(altura);
        capture.setImageWidth(largura);

        capture.start();
        opencv.Buffer=capture.grab();`code`

I now the program runs with 200MB of RAM.

Status of the problem: SOLVED :)

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart - But the unused objects would be removed eventually anyway.  GC runs automatically when occupied storage reaches a given threshold.  Running more often just increases the amount of CPU spent doing GC, with no real benefit.

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, but it would not be removed as quickly, hence you run out of memory faster.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart - No, you don't "run out of memory".  If you run out of memory it's because you've got too much stuff accessible -- more frequent GC will do nothing to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, the Java wrapper for OpenCV's `Mat` has a tiny footprint. The underlying native objects may be using gigabytes of memory (it was in my case) and the GC knows nothing about it.

The only 2 options are to:

- Manually deallocate native memory using `Mat.release()`.
- Call `System.gc()` every so often to force garbage collection of unreferenced `Mat` wrapper objects. Note, if you are using something like `VideoCapture` to read in frames, you will absolutely want to NOT call `System.gc()` every frame read as it will destroy performance. I call it about every 20 seconds in my application.

Comment: This answer plus the first answer reference to "this link" made it much clearer why I was getting an error and what to do about it. The underlying large native objects (OpenCV detectMultiScale face detection in my case) aren't released until the small Java objects' finalize() is run by gc().  But I have to force gc() since it doesn't see a problem yet because there are still Java megabytes freely available.